# Picker not populating in iOS6 but populating in iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios6, uipickerview

Have an odd thing happening with an app I'm on.
Firstly, the code and particular action within the app is fine when running on the iOS 5.1 simulator. When I run the same app on iOS 6.0 simulator, the action doesn't work.
Building the code on 5.1 sim produces an error free build. Building on 6.0 produces yellow warnings only.
I kind of expected this after some things being deprecated after the SDK upgrade.

The yellow warnings I have are of a deprecation but only that a Group Table View Background Color is now not available in 6.0 so I don't think that's affecting it.

Before posting code that works in 5.1, I'll explain.
I can fill, enter and save some text in a plain old text box. I then use that saved text to populate a picker in another tab.

As I say, works great with no problems in 5.1, seems not to work in 6.0.

Has anyone experienced similar things populating their pickers from 5.1 to 6.0?

Is their anything common that you guys know about before I delve deeper?

Many thanks for reading,

Gaz.

Comment: Definitely a Core Data issue guys!I've been using SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1 to look into the saved data.

The Core Data code that's being executed in 5.1 iPhone simulator is placing all the correct text field info into the correct Core Data entities. (There are 5 in total within my Core Data model)
When I ran exactly the same code in 6.0 iPhone simulator, the very same code is placing all 5 text fields into the last entity in my model, leaving the other 4 blank.
I've proved it by using the SQLite Database bowser!!
My next dilemma is.....how do I correct code that already works???

Answer (score 0):

please make sure the you have copied the yourDataBase.sqlite from iOS5 simulator to your application bundle in iOS6 simulator.